# SSRS Column Header Repeat in Corresponding Pages

Tags: reporting-services

I am a Beginner in SSRS where i am Getting this Random Conflict--My Column Headers are Not Repeating in the Next Pages of my RDL.

How to Achieve this?? Can you all please help me out.

Comment: There is a checkbox in the tablix properties that says "Repeat header rows on each page." Make sure it's checked.

Comment: Actually i have done Still i got Issue as soon as I worked on Advance Mode,Issue gets Resolved.Thanks for your comments!!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version SSRS you are running you may have to do it another way.  Select the tablix and then under the Columns Groups click the down arrow on the right of the header and select "Advanced".

[image: Advanced on Column Group]

Then under Row Groups select the Static item at the top. The properties should refresh and set the property "RepeatOnNewPage" to true and the "KeepWithGroup" to after.

[image: Static row group properties]